# Automate Safari web browser using c# on Windows

Tags: .net, windows, automation, safari, watin

I wondered if anyone had successfully managed, or knew how to automate the Safari web browser on the Windows platform.

Ideally I would like to automate Safari in a similar way to using [mshtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741317.aspx) for Internet Explorer. Failing that a way to inject JavaScript into the running process would also be fine. I've used the JavaScript injection method to automate Firefox via the [jssh](http://www.croczilla.com/jssh) plug-in.

I'm looking to automate the browser using .Net to enhance an existing automation framework [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)

**Edit**: Whilst I think selenium might be a great choice for automating Safari in certain scenarios, I would like to use a solution that does not require installing software on the server i.e. Selenium Core or an intermediate proxy server in the case of Selenium Remote Control.

**Update: 23-03-2009**:
Whilst I've not yet found a way to automate Safari, I have found a way to automate Webkit inside of Chrome. If you run Chrome using the --remote-shell-port=9999 command line switches (ref: http://www.ericdlarson.com/misc/chrome_command_line_flags.html) you can send javascript to the browser.

Once connected to the remote debug seesion

- Send **debug()** to attach to the current tab
- Send any javascript command using **print**, i.e. print document.window.location.href

We've used this method to add [Chrome support to WatiN](http://watin.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/watin/trunk/src/Core/Native/Chrome/)

Comment: If you get automated Safari on Windows working, I would be very interested in that.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Only via Chrome and webkit, as mentioned above. However it's pretty early on in development. Take a look at the latest WatiN sources for an idea.

Comment: I am thinking about adding support for Safari on Windows for Watir. We already have Chrome support, so that is not so interesting to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might check my post here where I am using the method described above to automate Chrome in C#

http://markcz.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/automating-chrome-browser-from-csharp/

Martin

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this helps, but the guys at [ArtOfTest](http://www.artoftest.com) have added Safari support to their .Net based automation framework WebAii.  Maybe you could figure out what they are doing.

Comment: I asked them and got automated reply that I will get an answer in 24 hours, but a few day later still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium](http://selenium.openqa.org/) has been very useful for me for compatibility testing.

Answer (score 1):

WatiN here http://watinandmore.blogspot.com/2010/01/browserattachto-and-iattachto.html lets you automate IE and FF. It is open source, so you can have a look on how they do it.

Maybe you can adapt it to your needs?